# Attach debugger (using eclipse) to play framework failed

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, playframework, playframework-2.0

I am using Scala to write a web on top of Play framework with eclipse IDE. I am trying to debug my app but hit debug attach failure. I tried to switch using Java instead of Scala,but I got same error. This is what I do.

1. Create a project and run `play clean compile`
2. run `play debug run`
3. in Eclipse, set 'debug configration' ->remote java application -> host: localhost, port:9999 and common: debug
4. in browser type in URL and enter: localhost:9999. Then get the following failure in play framework command line:
   Debugger failed to attach: handshake failed - received `>GET / HTTP/1.1< - expected >JDWP-Handshake<`

Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: Using proper tagging can help you...

Answer (score 10):

`localhost:9999` is what Eclipse is going to use to communicate with your application. On your browser, you still access your application on `localhost:9000` (default) or however you would access your application had you just done `play run`.

Basically, you've configured your debugging correctly in Eclipse.

1. Now, with your configuration selected from the **Debug Configuration**, click **Debug** (or selected your configuration from the **Debug As** toolbar button). Eclipse will attach to `localhost:9999`.
2. Browse to `localhost:9000` like you normally would to access your application.
3. That's it. Eclipse will pause on any breakpoints you have set, etc.